# RStudio: For-Loop with xtabs

Tags: r, for-loop, xtabs

Pretty simple: I'm trying to create a sequence of crosstabs. I thought all I needed was a for-loop and `xtabs`, but that hasn't worked out.

Say I have dataframe `df`, a list of column names `list1` and a second list `list2`. I have written the following loop:

```
for (i in list1) {  
    for (j in list2) {  
    print(prop.table(xtabs(~i+j,data=df),margin=2))} 
    }
```

However, when I run the loops, R spits out the following:

```
i1 j1 1
i1 j2 1
i1 j3 1
...
```

Why is this happening? If I write a standalone

`prop.table(xtabs(~i+j,data=df),margin=2)`

with a certain `i` and `j`, I receive the table I'm looking for. Why does it break when I try to iterate the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have `i` and `j` as character values from `list1` and `list2`. If that is true, you will need to build your formula from those values, such as with `as.formula` or `reformulate`. You can use `paste` to put together the formula so identical to what you have with your example.

```
for (i in list1) {  
  for (j in list2) {  
    print(prop.table(xtabs(formula = as.formula(paste("~", i, "+", j)), data = df), margin = 2))
  } 
}
```

Or alternatively can use in your loop:

```
print(prop.table(xtabs(formula = reformulate(c(i, j)), data = cgd), margin = 2))
```